# Confused about Ruby code placement

Tags: ruby, syntax, coding-style

So, I am getting into Ruby. I'm learning it everyday. And just like Spanish. I am getting able to read it, but not write it.

I am doing "Ruby the Hard Way" and I understand WHY things work, but the more I move through it the more I realize that I could not mimic the code if someone just came up to me and said "I need you to do so and so in Ruby."

I know that it is going to depend largely on what the task is, is how my code will be set up. But are there any tips and/or tricks for Ruby. (i.e. "Always write your variables first or strings before arrays" or something like that.

I'm unclear on when to write which lines of code or WHY something has to be below another block of code. I am aware of the nebulous nature of this question, but I'm looking for a bit of more broad rules for Ruby.

Comment: _I'm looking for a bit of more broad rules for Ruby_ Stack Overflow tends to look down on questions that are "broad." In fact, there is even an option when voting to put a question "On Hold" called "Too Broad". I would recommend finding a more specific question to ask about an exact topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the *WHY* in your question has to do with **learning** the concepts, but not really **applying** them in a way that's meaningful to you.

I'd recommend finding a task you can accomplish with Ruby. Eg: write to a file, get content out of a webpage, get the date/time in a specific country, whatever. Start small, but **challenge yourself**. Look at StackOverflow [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) tag, or [Github](https://github.com/) to see what other people are doing with Ruby.

That will get you thinking about the **problem** you're solving, and not the code alone; which is what programming is all about.

Then come back here and ask about the specifics you're struggling with.

Small disclaimer: yes, all of the above is my opinion; and as others have commented, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really too broad. I'll suppose that you know of another language already. If you are looking for code convention, look at the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Taking courses at [Code School](http://www.codeschool.com/paths/ruby) could get you an idea of the good practice (and make you learn useful frameworks like Rails. Reading "[The Ruby Way](http://therubyway.org/)" can give you a feeling of the "pulse" of the language. Building the blog application used by many Rails book could also help.

Finally, checkout sample Rails or Ruby projects from GitHub.

Comment: Thanks "Ruby the Way" helped.